# I get the data from mysql checkboxed it and send it back to mysql the records saves for only one student with id no 3

Tags: php, html, mysql

I get the data from mysql and display it in the table now i'm trying to send it to the database for each student by checking the checkbox, then what should i do to send all table data into the msql database with the different student id

```php
<form class="col-md-12" action="Attendance.php" method="post">
    <table id="example" class="myclass table table-striped"  />
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Full Name</th>
                <th>Father Name</th>
                <th><label><input type="checkbox" id="selectAll" name="chbox[]"> All Present </label></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
<?php 
$SrNo = 0;
global $dbManager;

$sql = "SELECT * FROM studentinfo";
$stmt = $dbManager->query($sql);

while($DataRows = $stmt->fetch()){
    $RollNo      = $DataRows['id'];
    $FullName  = $DataRows['fullname'];
    $FatherName  = $DataRows['fathername'];
?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $RollNo; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $FullName; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $FatherName; ?></td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="chbox[]" value="1" /></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    
<?php } ?>
        <tfoot>
<?php
  
if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){
    $StudentRollNo = $RollNo;
    $Attendance = $_POST['chbox'];

    // date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kabul");
    $CurrentTime = time();
    $DateTime = strftime("%B-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S", $CurrentTime);
   
    if(empty($Attendance)){
        $_SESSION['ErrorMessage'] = "Please filled all fields";
        RedirectTo("Attendance.php");
    }
    else{
        // the sql code is here.
        global $dbManager;
        foreach ($Attendance as $key => $value) {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO attendance(sid, subjectid, classid, attendance, datetime) VALUES(:studentId,'1','2', :attendancE, :dateTime)";
        $stmt = $dbManager->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindValue(':studentId',$StudentRollNo);
        $stmt->bindValue(':attendancE',$value);
        $stmt->bindValue(':dateTime',$DateTime);

        $Execute = $stmt->execute();

        if($Execute){
            $_SESSION['SuccessMessage'] = "Attendance Submited Successfully.";
            RedirectTo("Attendance.php");
        }
        else{
            $_SESSION['ErrorMessage'] = "Something went wrong. Try Again!";
            RedirectTo("Attendance.php");
        }
    }
      
}
?>
            <tr>
                <td>
                <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
                <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Save Attendance">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
</form>
```

**Mysql database: the problem is that the record saves only for one student.**

[image: mysql database the problem is that the record saves only for one student]

Comment: You need to pull the `<tr><td>....` into the `while` loop

Answer (score 0):

Bring you table inside the while loop where you are fetching the values from the database and then assign the value of students dynamically for the checkbox `value`

you can do

```
value="<?php echo $RollNo; ?>";
```

just like you echo out the other values add the echo into the value field of the checkbox in order to get the values dynamically assigned to each checkbox